How to land Geyser plugin to specific cpu cores?
I have a server with 64 cores. When I run solana-validator, I see that geyser plugin very unstable in term of latencies. My hypothesis is that because of sharing cpu with rpc node.
How to land rpc node to 0-50 cpu and geyser for 51-64?

geyser plugins are processes right? So the same thing you'd do for any other process - taskset - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994983/assigning-a-cpu-core-to-a-process-linux
